# Не выполняется повторно метод вызвавший java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: android

В AsyncTask выполняется подгрузка контента

```
try {
    f.load();
    //SystemClock.sleep(5000);
} catch ....
```

метод load()

```
public void load() throws IOException {
    if(currentPage == pageCount) return;
    setLoading(true);
    // выше код, который исполняется

    getNextContent();   // а этот метод может кинуть Exception
                        // и если кинет, то при повторном вызове  
                        // просто игнорируется

    //зато здесь код исполняется
    setLoading(false);
    currentPage++;
}
```

И вот если при первом вызове AsyncTask в getNextContent() вылетел java.net.UnknownHostException, который был обработан, то повторные попытки подгрузить данные ни к чему не приводят. При дебаге строка getNextContent() просто пропускается. Такое ощущение, что JVM запомнила что метод вызвал исключение и попросту его игнорирует. Думаю я что-то еще не знаю в теме JAVA, но что?

Comment: А можно весь код глянуть? Особенно метода load

Comment: Вы что-то путаете, вызовы методов не могут пропускаться.

Comment: А Вы breakpoint внутри метода `getNextContent()` ставить пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо за отзывы. Перезепустил ИДЕА, сделал ребуилд и все заработало как нужно. Так и не понял в чем прикол был